# Cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jar

**My Code:**

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:assets/OPTIONS_" + jubilar1.getJubiLanguage().toUpperCase() + ".docx")));
```

I have already tried instead of .getFile(), extractJarFileFromURL or resource.getInputStream() but all this does not work. When I package my project and run it as a jar file and it tries to open the following file it always returns the following message.

**Error:**

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [assets/OPTIONS_DE.
> docx] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not
> reside in the file system:
> jar:file:/home/tkf6y/IdeaProjects/hrapps/backend/target/backend-3.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/assets/OPTIONS_EN.docx

Comment: The error isn't wrong. It isn't a `java.util.File` as it isn't a physical file on the file system it is part of a jar. You can use the `InputStream` (and should) to read it regardless of the location. There is an `OPCPackage.open` method which takes an `Inputstream`.

Comment: No, that was not the problem. However, I have solved it now. I changed my code line to the following:

 `code`XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/OPTIONS_" + jubilar1.getJubiLanguage().toUpperCase() + ".docx"))); `code`


I removed ResourceUtils.getFile() and used instead getClass().getResourceAsStream(). Then you can also do it without classpath:.

Comment: So yes it was the problem, as you are now using an `InputStream` as I suggested. The problem was (and always has been) the `getFile` stuff. What I suggest to do is don't use what you have now but rather do a `new ClassPathResource(your location).getInputStream())` instead, it is easier, or even use a `ResourceLoader` (a Spring interface you can inject) and then use the path you had an again use `getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So yes it was the problem, as you are now using an InputStream as I suggested. The problem was (and always has been) the getFile stuff. What I suggest to do is don't use what you have now but rather do a new ClassPathResource(your location).getInputStream()) instead, it is easier, or even use a ResourceLoader (a Spring interface you can inject) and then use the path you had an again use getInputStream(). –

Comment: Hi @joni do you know how to create a file while my spring application is in the docker container? If you can answer my question,  thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
        String strJson = null;
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("json/data.json");
        try {
            byte[] binaryData = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(classPathResource.getInputStream());
            strJson = new String(binaryData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```